# Nginx redirect based on query string

Tags: nginx

I'm migrating old website links to new website, it will use same domain

Here is some old links.

| Old Links | New links |
| --- | --- |
| http://example.com/?p=contact | /contact |
| http://example.com/?p=static&id=career | /career |
| http://example.com/?p=static&id=about | /about |
| http://example.com/?p=catalog&action=images&cat_id=1 | /product-category/category-slug-1 |
| http://example.com/?p=catalog&action=images&cat_id=2 | /product-category/category-slug-2 |
| http://example.com/?p=catalog&action=viewimages&pid=1&cat_id=1 | /product/product-slug-1 |
| http://example.com/?p=catalog&action=viewimages&pid=2&cat_id=3 | /product/product-slug-2 |

The new product page doesn't have id in the URL, so I list all of them manually, and they are just 5 categories and 20 product pages in total.

This is what I've tried before I knew that nested if is not supported.

```
location / {
    if ($arg_p = contact) { return 301 /contact; }
    if ($arg_p = static) { 
        if ($arg_id = career) { return 301 /career; }
        # other static pages redirect to /about
        return 301 /about;
    }

    if ($arg_p = catalog) {
        if ($arg_action = images) {
            if ($arg_cat_id = 1) { return 301 /product-category/category-slug-1; }
            if ($arg_cat_id = 2) { return 301 /product-category/category-slug-2; }
            # other unlisted categories should redirect to /product-categories
            return 301 /product-categories;
        }
        if ($arg_action = viewimages) {
            if ($arg_pid = 1) { return 301 /product/product-slug-1/; }
            if ($arg_pid = 2) { return 301 /product/product-slug-2/; }
        }
        # other unlisted links defaults to /products
        return 301 /products;
    }
}
```

What is the config should be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with several chained [`map`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_map_module.html) blocks. Here is an idea:

```
map $arg_p $url_p {
    contact    /contact;
    static     $url_id;
    catalog    $url_action;
    # default value will be an empty string
}

map $arg_id $url_id {
    career     /career;
    about      /about;
    # other static pages redirect to /about
    default    /about;
}

map $arg_action $url_action {
    images     $url_cat_id;
    viewimages $url_pid;
    # other unlisted actions defaults to /products
    default    /products;
}

map $arg_cat_id $url_cat_id {
    1          /product-category/category-slug-1;
    2          /product-category/category-slug-2;
    # other unlisted categories should redirect to /product-categories
    default    /product-categories;
}

map $arg_pid $url_pid {
    1          /product/product-slug-1;
    2          /product/product-slug-2;
    # other unlisted products defaults to /products
    default    /products;
}

server {
    listen ...
    server_name ...
    ...
    if ($url_p) { # if '$url_p' variable is not an empty string
        return 301 $url_p;
    }
    location / {
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

Some `map` blocks can be shortened, for example, lets assume you have 3 static pages `/career`, `/clients` and "default" page `/about`, 5 categories and 45 products:

```
map $arg_id $url_id {
    ~^(career|clients)$        /$1;
    default                    /about;
}

map $arg_cat_id $url_cat_id {
    ~^([1-5])$                 /product-category/category-slug-$1;
    default                    /product-categories;
}

map $arg_pid $url_pid {
    ~^([1-9]|[1-3]\d|4[0-5])$  /product/product-slug-$1;
    default                    /products;
}
```

**Update**

OP states he can't use `map` directive since he doesn't have an access to full nginx config but only to `server` block contents. While previous solution is far more elegant (and should be more effective in terms of performance), it is possible to do the same using only `if` blocks:

```
if ($arg_p = contact) { return 301 /contact; }

if ($arg_p = static) { set $page static_$arg_id; }
if ($page = static_career) { return 301 /career; }
if ($page) { return 301 /about; } # anything that is not 'career' redirected to '/about'

if ($arg_p = catalog) { set $action $arg_action; }

if ($action = images) { set $page category_$arg_cat_id; }
if ($page = category_1) { return 301 /product-category/category-a; }
if ($page = category_2) { return 301 /product-category/category-b; }
# ... other categories
if ($action = images) { return 301 /product-categories; } # unlisted category specified

if ($action = viewimages) { set $page product_$arg_pid; }
if ($page = product_1) { return 301 /product/product-a; }
if ($page = product_2) { return 301 /product/product-b; }
# ... other products
if ($action = viewimages) { return 301 /products; } # unlisted product specified

# if you want to process any unlisted action in some special way
# if ($action) { ... } # 'action' query argument neither 'images' nor 'viewimages'
```

This fragment can be placed either in `server` or `location` context.

Comment: I got `nginx: [emerg] "map" directive is not allowed here`. Does map can not be used inside `server` block? I don't have access to modify nginx outside `server` block.

Comment: Found these question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27358804/, so I think map is not an option for me. Is it possible to do just rewrite (regex for old query params) (new links)? I don't understand much about regex.

Comment: That's a nice trick to concat the query params and store them as a variable.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up with this solution.

```
location / {
  if ($arg_p = contact) { return 301 /contact; }
  if ($args ~ p=static&id=career) { return 301 /career; }
  if ($arg_p = static) { return 301 /about; }
  if ($args ~ p=catalog&action=images&cat_id=1) { return 301 /product-category/category-a; }
  if ($args ~ p=catalog&action=images&cat_id=2) { return 301 /product-category/category-b; }
  # and other cat_id
  if ($args ~ p=catalog&action=viewimages&pid=1&cat_id=1) { return 301 /product/product-a; }
  if ($args ~ p=catalog&action=viewimages&pid=2&cat_id=1) { return 301 /product/product-b; }
  # and other pid
  if ($arg_p = catalog) { return 301 /products; } #other p=catalog defaults to /products
  try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
}
```

It's working, but it can't handle the case when the query params order is not written below, e.g `/?id=career&p=static` (id and p is switched around)

Also `cat_id` in `p=catalog&action=viewimages` is not used, but when I remove the `cat_id` from the rules, `p=catalog&action=viewimages&pid=10` always redirects to `p=catalog&action=viewimages&pid=1`, so I had to put the `cat_id`.

If someone had better idea to handle dynamic order for the query params, feel free to post as an answer. I'll mark it as accepted if it works.

EDIT: For dynamic order query params and much more cleaner if, see [Ivan Shatsky's answer](https://serverfault.com/a/1077432/609076)

Comment: See the update to my answer.